# No Intellisense for Unity Assembly-CSharp scripts when working in Assembly-CSharp-Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, unity3d-editor

I am having an issue with Unity, where Visual Studio 2017 will not recognize classes in the standard Assembly-CSharp project when working on custom editor scripts in Assembly-CSharp-Editor.

Everything compiles correctly in Unity and functions as expected, however I get no IntelliSense for MonoBehaviour classes when working in Editor scripts, and Visual Studio gives me "type or namespace could not be found" errors as shown:

[image]

The solution layout can be seen here, I don't think I've done anything odd:

[image]

I've tried re-importing everything into Unity, deleting the solution and project files so that Unity will recreate them, but no joy.

Is there something obvious I am missing or does anyone have any insight? Thanks.

Comment: Have the same issue, asked about it here: 
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1727713/visual-studio-editor-project-assembly-csharp-edito.html

It happened after upgrading to Unity 2020.2.0a9 and then downgrading to 2019.3.12f1.

Comment: Someone in the other thread suggested downgrading to 2019.3.11f1 and that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks @Pking. I went to get 2019.3.11f1 after reading your answer and it turns out that there is a new version coincidentally released just yesterday that fixes this issue. It is fixed in [2019.3.13f1](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/referenceoutputassembly-key-is-set-to-false-in-project-references). If you want to add this as an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is an issue introduced with Unity 2019.3.12f1. Upgrading to 2019.3.13f1 fixes the issue.